# Don't want to see whether contacts are 'active now' in messenger

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

Is there a way to turn this off? I don't want to see whether my contacts are 'active now.'

Answer (score 1):

No there is no direct way to do so. Alternatively you can turn off chat on messenger then you will not see 'Active Now' status of your contacts.

Note: When you turn chat off, you'll still get your messages, but people won't see a green small circle (online symbol) next to your name, and you won't appear in the Active tab.

Comment: I went to settings and unchecked 'Facebook chat,' but I still see whether my friends are active, or how long ago (under their name when I click on a conversation)

Comment: It will not show they are active or not, it will show how long ago they were active and after sometime it will not show that also.

Comment: No it still shows it.. Assuming I've turned off the right thing: Settings / facebook chat

Comment: First thing you have to know that there is difference between messenger and Facebook chat. When you turn off the Facebook chat and again click on chat to see who is online you will also be online not offline.

Comment: ok! So I guess I'm only turning off the _facebook_-chat. How do I turn off "chat on messenger," as you write in your answer? I can't see that anywhere in the settings (only the "facebook chat").

Comment: Messenger is an app.

Comment: Ok, very helpful. Do you mean that I should turn off messenger entirely? If I remember right then facebook won't let me send messages on the phone (or maybe I was tricked by whatever prompts made me install it)?

Comment: Turning off chat on messenger means it will not show you online and also you will not see who is online. But you will be able to receive message and can reply also. You will be able to send message to anyone.

Comment: ok! But how do I do this? I only see "facebook chat" in the settings of messenger

Answer (score 1):

You can actually hide it. You have to do it from the messenger app on your phone. You will open messenger and it should pop up and show a list on conversations but at the very top there are 4 options you can click on. You'll click on the 3rd one over. It's like 3 bullet points with lines beside it. Once you click on that you will see something that says messenger and active. Click on the Active tab. There is a little on/off switch beside your name. Slide it to off. And now people can't see if you are online or when you were last online.

Comment: This was probably updated. I don't see those 4 options.